# Unable to post data in drop down list from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I am new in writing code. Getting following error when trying to post data in drop down list from DB. 
My Objective is: Post data in Drop Down List from DB.

> Error message: Process can't access the file because it is being used
>   by another process

[image]

```
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;



public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Database1;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Populate1();

    }


    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /* SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into service_type (type) values(' " + TextBox1.Text + " ')",
             new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));

         cmd.Connection.Open(); 
         cmd.Connection.Close();
         cmd.Connection.Dispose(); */

        con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.CommandText = "insert into service_type (type) values(' " + TextBox1.Text + " ')";

         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
    }

    public void Populate1()
    {

        con.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [serice_type]", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
       cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues;
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DropDownList1.DataSource = ddlValues;
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "theType";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "theType";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }



}
```

Comment: Well the error message given is quite a good indication of what is wrong.  Your Database1.mdf file is being locked, since it is open else where.  Close all applications that might use Database1.mdf

Comment: Indeed, probably by the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Attach your db to sql server (if not already attached). Change your connection string "Database=" to "Initial Catalog="

Comment: Replaced "Database=" to "Initial Catalog=". And this Database is not opened by any other application like SQL Server Management Studio.  Now giving Error message: Database 'C:\GERP\gerp_support\App_Data\Database1.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Database1.mdf' as database 'Database1'.

Comment: @tede24 My DB is already attached to sql server.